# android activty start from service always show even re launching the app. need to start first activity when app is relaunch

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have an activity A. now i start a service using

```
startService(new Intent(A.this,Service.class));
```

now after some times (since it is performing some task in background , you can move anywhere in phone , so lets stay at phone home screen) service stops and start an another activity B (now B is on Top) which show result.  Current i am on screen B. my problem is when i am on B and press back , it does not show activity A. even if i exist from app(through back button) and again I launch the app it show activity B. since my starting activity is A so i want to show A not B. please guide me how can i do this.

Comment: Are you using the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag when starting the B activity? If yes, you need to remove that, since it will start a new stack of activities that doesn't contain your initial activity (A).

Comment: i tried both . first using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and second without this. but none of them worked.

Comment: Then you probably have the no history flag set on activity A in your manifest file.

Comment: i also tried this but didnt work :)

Comment: how is your code exiting from Activity A. A finish() would make the activity disappear from the history stack.

Comment: yeah that's the problem. user can exit from back button.